# как соединить процессы?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  char v='y';
    do
{
    cout << "1. Copy File" << endl;
    cout << "2. Move File" << endl;
    cout << "3. Rename File" << endl;
    cout << "4. Delete File" << endl;
    cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl;
    cout << "6. Search" << endl;
    cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl;
    cout << "8. Download File\n" << endl;

v=getch();
if (v=='1')
{
  cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;

char path1[100], path2[100];
cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
cin >> (path1);
cout << endl;
cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
cin >> (path2);

CopyFile(path1,path2, true);
cout << endl;
cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
cin >> v;
if (v=='y') system("cls");
}
}
while (v != 'n');

if (v=='2')
{ char q;
  cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;

char path1[100], path2[100];
cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
cin >> (path1);
cout << endl;
cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
cin >> (path2);

CopyFile(path1,path2, true);
cout << endl;
cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
cin >> q;
if (v=='y') system("cls");
}
}
while (q != 'n');

system("PAUSE"); 
}
```

выдает ошибку, я хочу чтобы программа использовала разные функции, поможете слить код в единое?

Comment: отформатируйте код

Comment: А причем здесь **процессы** ?

И что за ошибка ?